# How fast are fast mounts shared with lower level characters

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Mounts are shared between all characters on the account.

If you have 2 characters, one of which is over level 40, and the other of which is between 20 and 40, and the higher level character buys a swift mount (200% movement), can the lower level character use it? If so, do they get the 200% speed rating, or are they limited to 160%? (Assuming they only have apprentice riding.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All mounts now will auto-scale to the skill of the rider. If you have a higher riding (or flying) skill, the mount will fly faster, if you are level 20, it will ride at 60% (the standard level 20 speed), regardless of the mount.

There are exceptions, such as the Sea Turtle, which do not increase speed with riding skill.